# how to add two serializeArray() in one variable in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have two variable having value of searializeArry like this -:

```
var Data = $("#searchValue").serializeArray();
var Data_filter =$("#filter_head_area_form").serializeArray();
```

I want to send both the array value in Var Data . So that my ajax call will be like this

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'something.com',        
                type:"post",
                data : Data,
```

Comment: Or you can use [**.extend()**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var Data = $("#searchValue").serializeArray();
var Data_filter =$("#filter_head_area_form").serializeArray();

Data = Data.concat(Data_filter)
```

Or you can send

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'something.com',        
   type:"post",
   data : {
     Data: Data,
     Data_filter: Data_filter
   }
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $.ajax({
                url: 'something.com',        
                type:"post",
                data : Data.concat(Data_filter),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it using below statement

```
$("#searchValue, #filter_head_area_form").serializeArray();
```